# Ant Classpath Error When Unzipping Input File Java

Tags: java, ant

I'm a beginner with ant and am wondering what this error means. "failed to create task or type classpath" It gives me that error on the line that is unzipping the file.

```
<project name="Project2" default="run">

<target name="compile" depends="clean">
   <javac srcdir="." includeantruntime="false"/>
</target> 

<target name="clean">
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.class"/>
    </delete>
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="." includes="META-INF"/>
        </delete>
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="." includes="*.*~"/>
    </delete>
</target>

<target name="getInput">
    <get src="file.zip" dest="."/>
    <unzip src="folder.zip" dest="folder"/>
</target>

<target name="run" depends= "compile, who, getInput" > 
    <java classname="Driver" fork="yes"/>
    <classpath path = "."/>
</target>

<target name="who">
    <echo message="Name"/>
</target>

<target name="jar"> 
    <jar destfile="project2.jar" basedir="."/>
</target>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this is what you should do:
put the src values to have the same value
check if the source file exists under the project root